# fabric js as ES6 import in Chrome doesn't work

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

On my website I don't want to bundle but instead use ES6 modules directly (works for the audience)

I try importing fabric.js by

`import {fabric} from "../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js";` like I do when I bundle (for bundles it works fine).

however when starting the website I get

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
>   '../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js' does not provide an export
>   named 'fabric'"

if I change the above to 
`import * as FAB from "../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js";` 
I get

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fabric' of undefined
>       at fabric.js:3224

Any ideas on how to use fabric directly as ES6 module without bundling?
Needless to say I do not have this issue with other modules I import when using Chrome 76.0.3809.132

Upgraded to fabric 3.4 with no avail. Let me paste my entire code here: The html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script type="module" src="./start.js"></script>
   </head>

   <body>

   </body>
</html>
```

and the JS from which I removed everything else

`import fabric from '../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.min.js';`

Still same Error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module
>   '../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.min.js' does not provide an export
>   named 'default'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way fabric.js is written, it won't work with ES6 Module import. This is because fabric relies on `this` being a reference to `window` in browser environments, e.g. when it uses IIFEs to add properties to the `fabric` object like this:

```
(function(global) {

  var fabric  = global.fabric || (global.fabric = { }),

  // ...
  fabric.something = somethingElse
})(typeof exports !== 'undefined' ? exports : this);
```

Normally, `this` would be passed as a reference to `window`, but not when the script is loaded as a Module ([MDN mentions it here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/globalThis#Description) among other places).

That's why even if you correctly import it via

```
import fabric from '../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.js'
```

You'll get errors like

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fabric' of undefined
```

Unless you want to get your hands dirty and patch the library source, you'd probably be better off loading fabric in a separate, non-module script tag.

Comment: i wonder if there is a way to make both way work. commonJs ans es module.

Answer (score 1):

Please try to import it like the below,

```
import fabric from '../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.min.js'


class App extends Component {

  render() {
    console.log(fabric) // you can get fabric object
    return (
      <div class="blahblah"> 
      </div>
    )

  }
}
```

Comment: Still get Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'. Does it work for you? Which fabric version do you use? I am on 3.3.2

Comment: Yes it works for me. Mine is create-react-app and am using fabric 3.4.0 and my package is fabric and yo can install like "npm i fabric"

Comment: Try to upgrade your fabric to 3.4.0 and see.. mine s Workin as expected.

Comment: tried that. Unfortunately no different result. It's really ridiculous as the code is so simple and I even removed everything else from JS file. Any ideas?

Comment: You are seeing same issue? I meant the messag6

Comment: create react app does bundle. he stated clearly he does not want to bundle.

Comment: yes. Still get "Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '../node_modules/fabric/dist/fabric.min.js' does not provide an export named 'default'"

Answer (score 0):

importing in this way works for me

```
 import { fabric } from "fabric"
```